# VBA Macro Copy and Paste, pasting to discrete locations

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I'm trying to write a macro to copy and paste information from one sheet to another depending on whether it is marked as "Upcoming / Complete / In Progress" in column J on the original sheet (This is called the "Tracker").
It works - but the problem is that it is copying the whole row from the tracker sheet and I only want it to copy columns A:K. Ideally it would post the results to different places on Sheet1 depending on the status but I can always bodge another macro to do that afterwards! I must confess I'm hatcheting an existing macro as I'm a bit weak at VBA so that may be part of the problem. Many thanks guys.

```
Sub Copybasedonstatus()
'Niall McCracken 12/12/16

Dim lRow, cRow As Integer        
lRow = Sheets("Tracker").Range("A800").End(xlUp).Row

For j = lRow To 1 Step -1    
    If Sheets("Tracker").Range("J" & j) = "Upcoming" Then
        cRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A800").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Tracker").Rows(j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & cRow + 1)

    ElseIf Sheets("Tracker").Range("J" & j) = "Complete" Then
        cRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A800").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Tracker").Rows(j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & cRow + 1)

    ElseIf Sheets("Tracker").Range("J" & j) = "In Progress" Then
        cRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A800").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Tracker").Rows(j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & cRow + 1)

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: why is the difference in the code inside your `If`s , in all of them you are performing the same things, `cRow` gets the same value, and the paste is to "Sheet1" in all cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xOnce you decide what (or where) you want to paste the copied rows (column A:K) , let me know and I can modify accordingly.

I use the `With Sheets("Tracker")` statement to make the code shorter (also helps reduce bugs) , also I replaced your `If`s with `Select Case .Range("J" & j).Value`.

**Note**: there is no real need to loop backwards if you are not deleting rows or cells. You could use a regular `For j = 1 To lRow` if you wanted.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copybasedonstatus()

'Niall McCracken 12/12/16

Dim lRow As Long, cRow As Long, j As Long

With Sheets("Tracker")
    lRow = .Range("A800").End(xlUp).Row

    ' another method of finding last row in Column A (skipping blank cells in the middle)
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For j = lRow To 1 Step -1
        cRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A800").End(xlUp).Row

        Select Case .Range("J" & j).Value
            Case "Upcoming"
                .Range("A" & j & ":K" & j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & cRow + 1)

            Case "Complete"
                .Range("A" & j & ":K" & j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & cRow + 1)

            Case "In Progress"
                .Range("A" & j & ":K" & j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & cRow + 1)

        End Select
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thanks thats amazing (I did wonder about the looping backwards as the output is a bit weird!). Ideally I would like to paste just cells A:K anywhere on Sheet1 but if possible separate by status - so In Progress would be something like B1 to B50, Upcoming B60:B110 and complete B115:B165. Super thanks.

Comment: @NiallMcCracken  you're welcome, please mark as answer

Comment: Super thats done now, any further advice on moving is appreciated!

Comment: @NiallMcCracken open a new post with your updated code, and describe what is the next step you are trying to achieve , this will allows other users besides me helping you